# How to read textfiles instead of using cases?

Tags: c#, checkbox, multiple-choice

I'm working on a project where I display questions in Textboxes. Underneath each one of them there are 4 checkboxes and the user has to select the one that answers to the question.

Is there any way I can just put all my questions, answers, etc in a .txt file and load them from there?
I don't want to have have to write a `case` for each and every question(I have 120 questions approximately).

My way of doing it so far:

```
    case 5: // Multiple Answers
                txtQuestion.Text = "What are the characteristics of the " +
                                   "Main method? (Choose two)";

                grpSingleChoice.Visible = false;
                grpMultipleChoice.Visible = true;

                chkAnswer1.Text = "A. It must always return void";
                chkAnswer2.Text = "B. It is always the first method inside the " +
                                  "main class of a program";
                chkAnswer3.Text = "C. It is the start and end point of a program";
                chkAnswer4.Text = "D. It must always be passed an array of strings " +
                                  "as in static void Main(string[] args)";
                chkAnswer5.Visible = true;
                chkAnswer5.Text = "E. It must be created inside of a class" +
                                  "or a structure";
                break;
```

Comment: Even better: use a database ;)

Comment: Yes there are - have a go and let us know a specific question because at the moment its too broad a question to answer. There are too many possible solution.s

Comment: You might consider an XML file, also. You can have "Question" elements and "Answer" elements.

Comment: For this I can't use a database it's not allowed. The person requested specifically not to use a database (don't know why he wouldn't cause it's much better but hey !). I'm actually looking to put the q & a & possible comment in just a textfile. is that possible?

Comment: Many, many ways to do this. If you can fit each question and each answer on one line a low-fi way would be to prefix each question with a 'Q', then add those answers and finally one line witha solution, maybe 'SB' for 'B'; then read from Q to S process and repeat..
For processing you would use the substrings line.SubString(0,1) and line.SubString(1)..

Comment: Use XML if you can't use a database

Comment: Not really formilliar with that , how would that work?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this can be:

```
[START]
Question = Imagine you write code and include a backslash in a string, the compiler ...
Correct = 2
Option = Answer a
Option = Answer b
Option = Answer c
Option = Answer d
[END]
```

The "tags" will be your loop conditions, so just use `Split(lineText, " = ")` to get the values. 
But XML is much better solution :

```
<xml>
    <question correct="2">
        <description>Imagine you write code and include a backslash in a string, the compiler ....</description>
        <option>answer</option>
        <option>answer</option>
        <option>answer</option>
        <option>answer</option>
    </question>
    <question correct="3">
        <description>Another question....</description>
        <option>answer</option>
        <option>answer</option>
        <option>answer</option>
        <option>answer</option>
    </question> 
</xml>
```